# Plot training, validation and test set on same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

This is how I segmented the data

```
(X, y), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, 
                                                  y, 
                                                  test_size=0.1, 
                                                  random_state=1)
```

The below code plots X_train and X_val, I would like to add X_test the plot

```
history = model.fit(
    x= X_train,
    y= y_train,
    epochs = 10,
    validation_data = (X_val, y_val),
    batch_size = 128
)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Is it also possible to plot the `test_loss` on top of this to get an overview of all three on the same plot?

There is no `history.history['test_loss']`.

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding something like `plt.plot(history.history['test_loss']))`?

Comment: when I print `history.history` it only has loss and val_loss but no test_loss

Comment: And what exactly are you referring to by `test_loss`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 please check now hope its clearer

Comment: What happens if you use `plt.plot(X_test)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it ruins the image since it plots all 10,000 points along with 784 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not calculate test_loss yet.
You first need to predict some labels using X_test and then calculate the loss based on the predicted values and y_test. Alternatively, you can use evaluate to do that directly:

```
test_loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

You cannot plot them together since test_loss is a single value that is calculated once at the end of training and not every epoch like validation.

Nevertheless, you should not use X_test and y_test in training as you will have trained on the whole available data so you can't test anymore.

X_test and y_test are to be used solely at the end of all the steps to test the performance of the model.

The validation data serves the purpuse of "test data" while you are training. After you have done all the training and optimization you can then retrain the network on the combined dataset of train ad validation, and use the resulting network to test it's performace on the test dataset (X_test, y_test)

Comment: can I also calculate the model.fit again with the x_test passed to model validation set and plot it ?

Comment: you can but the weights are going to change as compared to when you got the val_loss. Anyway You shouldn't use X_test and y_test att all until the end of your optimization as a measure of the models performace

Comment: @Matthew so will you accept the answer or, do you want some other information?